# MySQL Count number of Items with Group By

Tags: php, mysql

We have these two fields in our MySQL database:
**in_model** , **in_color**

And we are trying to count the total of model (in_model field), which has the same color (in_color field) in PHP with MySQL as backend database. We tried using the `count()` function, together with the `group by`. But it would seem we don't have achieve a desired result

#### This is our MySQL database:

```
$query = "SELECT in_model, COUNT(in_color) FROM in_newunit GROUP BY in_color,in_model";         
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(in_color)'] ."  
         ". $row['in_model'] ."  items.";   
    echo "<br />";  
}
```

#### This is the output we are receiving

```
There are 1 C2I items. 
There are 2 try items. 
There are 2 try items. 
There are 4 C2I items.
```

#### This is what we are trying to achieve

We are trying to have the color appear in the echo

```
There are 1 C2I Black items. 
There are 2 try White items. 
There are 2 try Black items. 
There are 4 C2I White items.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is straight enough. Try this.

```
$query = "SELECT in_model, in_color, count(*) AS counter FROM in_newunit GROUP BY in_model, in_color";         
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo "There are ". $row['counter'] ." ". $row['in_model'] ." ".$row['in_color']." items.";   
    echo "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: This one works. And we didn't use the counter. We didn't thought of using an Alias to make it display in PHP. Again Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The query is actually the other way around:

```
SELECT in_color, count(*) FROM in_newunit
GROUP BY in_color
```

And you have actually said it yourself:

> we are trying to count the total of model (in_model field), which has the same color (in_color field)

"count the total of model" > `count(*)`

"which has the same color" > for every color the previous count, which is a `group by in_color`

Also note that if you do `count(in_model)` you won't be counting values with `in_model` as `null`. If you do `count(*)` you will be counting the `null` values too. Up to you.

**Update**

So you want the amount of elements there are by (model, color) pair. Then this is the query:

```
SELECT in_model, in_color, count(*) FROM in_newunit
GROUP BY in_model, in_color
```

Eg:

```
model1 | black | 2
model1 | white | 1
model2 | black | 5
model3 | white | 4
```

Comment: What we want is to have a COLOR in our output for example:
1 C2I items - Output
1 C2I Black items - Desired Output

Comment: @Mostly Mostacho :

Yes I already tried what you suggested, but the echo still lacks an output. 
It still does not show the color example:

There are 4 C2I White items.

The output is still showing:
There are 4 CSI items.

As you can see the output lacks the in_color field

Comment: Updated the answer... I didn't realise that there were 2 similar models with different colors in the expected output (I thought you wanted the amount per color as you mentioned in the text I cited... but your example actually shows that it should be grouped by both model and color)

Comment: Uhm, okay... This is getting a bit confusing on my part honestly, so how do I fetch the data and display it.

Comment: You just need to apply the same logic you applied in the code of your question. Give it a try.